# Не работает Чат на yii2

Tags: yii2, chat

Всем доброго времени суток. Хотел добавить этот https://github.com/sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte чат на yii2. Не работает хотя сделал все по инструкции. Не знаю в чем проблема. Помогите кто может.

Установил по инструкции через composer.

```
"sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte": "dev-master"
```

Создал таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE `chat` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` TEXT,
  `updateDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

В контроллер добавил

```
public function actionSendChat() {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if ($message) {
        $model = new Chat;
        $model -> message = $message;
        if ($model -> save()) {
            echo ChatRoom::data();
        } else {
            print_r($model -> getErrors());
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

И вью

```
 <?php
            echo \sintret\chat\ChatRoom::widget([
                    'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/chat/send-chat']),
                    'userModel'=>  \app\modules\user\models\User::className(),
                    'userField'=>'avatarImage'
                ]
            );
            ?>
```

Модель User Указал и там есть поле как и требовалось avatarImage(хотя если его не будет то установится дефолтная своя картинка)

При открытии вью формы `sendChat.php`
 появляется ошибка из контроллера

```
Undefined index: message
```

в строчке

`$message = $_POST['message'];`

Проверил так в другую вьюшку(users) добавил

```
 <?php
            echo \sintret\chat\ChatRoom::widget([
                    'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/chat/send-chat']),
                    'userModel'=>  \app\modules\user\models\User::className(),
                    'userField'=>'avatarImage'
                ]
            );
            ?>
```

Показывает Чат так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

переменную $message из контроллера приравнял на string слово $message ='Hello';
и обновил не рабочую форму sendChat и теперь эта переменная записалась в базе и появилась в вьюшке(users) о которой говорил выше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите с этой проблемой

Comment: Я не могу сказать, что это вам поможет, но, пожалуйста, замените `$message = $_POST['message'];`, на `$message = \Yii::$app->request->post('message');`, т.к. так делать правильно, если вы используете Yii2.

Comment: @withoutname Thanks problem with $message has disappear. But it's still not working

Comment: я думаю это уже проблемы самого виджета.

Comment: @withoutname Может вы знаете какой нибудь чат реализованный на yii2? Эти не подошли http://phptrends.com/dig_in/yii2-chat